# RewardedVideoAd MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this) is deprecated. What is the new alternative?

Tags: android, ads, deprecated, admob-rewardedvideoad, google-ads-api

RewardedVideoAd is deprecated. What is the new alternative?

```
    void loadAds(){

        RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(rewarded_id, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);

        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
            AppUtils.showLog("REWARDED", "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded");
        }
        .....
        .....

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the new way to implement new RewardVideoAds. Found via this [official website](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads).

**Load an ad**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAd;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private RewardedAd rewardedAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this,
        "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");

    RewardedAdLoadCallback adLoadCallback = new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdLoaded() {
            // Ad successfully loaded.
        }

       @Override
        public void onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
            // Ad failed to load.
        }
    };
    rewardedAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), adLoadCallback);
}
}
```

**Show the ad**

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (rewardedAd.isLoaded()) {
        Activity activityContext = MainActivity.this
        RewardedAdCallback adCallback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                // Ad opened.
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                // Ad closed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem reward) {
                // User earned reward.
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(AdError adError) {
                // Ad failed to display.
            }
        };
        rewardedAd.show(activityContext, adCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad wasn't loaded yet.");
    }
}
});
```

**Using RewardedAdCallback to preload the next rewarded ad**

```
public RewardedAd createAndLoadRewardedAd() {
    RewardedAd rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
    RewardedAdLoadCallback adLoadCallback = new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdLoaded() {
            // Ad successfully loaded.
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
            // Ad failed to load.
        }
    };
    rewardedAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), adLoadCallback);
    return rewardedAd;
}

@Override
public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
    this.rewardedAd = createAndLoadRewardedAd();
}
```

Comment: This is now deprecated too. The answer should be updated.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded) is the latest way which I have implemented recently [May - 2023]

**Declare a RewardedAd:**

```
private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
```

**Inside the onCreate(), load a rewarded ad object:**

```
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
      adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
          // Handle the error.
          Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.toString());
          rewardedAd = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd ad) {
          rewardedAd = ad;
          Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.");
        }
    });
```

**Show the ad:**

```
if (rewardedAd != null) {
  Activity activityContext = MainActivity.this;
  rewardedAd.show(activityContext, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
    @Override
    public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
      // Handle the reward.
      Log.d(TAG, "The user earned the reward.");
      int rewardAmount = rewardItem.getAmount();
      String rewardType = rewardItem.getType();
    }
  });
} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.");
}
```

For more information, you can react out the [documentation.](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded)

Rewarded ads example: [Java](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/java/admob/RewardedVideoExample) | [Kotlin](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/kotlin/admob/RewardedVideoExample)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new class RewardedAd that should be used instead now. See [the Google API docs here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/rewarded/RewardedAd).